# create a new connection and connect to hidden network disappears from network bar

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

My wireless network card is **broadcom b4313**,the default wireless driver installed with ubuntu 14.04 was not supporting access point mode.

So I removed the default driver and installed **brcmsmac driver** but after installing  `create a new connection` and `connect to hidden network` options not showing in network bar and also `available wifi networks` also not showing.

Am I only able to create hotsopt connection through `ap-hotspot`?